# pandas dataframe filter by sequence of values in a specific column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe

A B C

1 2 3

2 3 4

3 8 7

I want to take only rows where there is a sequence of 3,4 in columns C (in this scenario - first two rows)

What will be the best way to do so?

Comment: @jezrael -- I don't think that's the right duplicate, OP is looking for a sequence not anywhere `in`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shift`

```
In [1085]: s = df.eq(3).any(1) & df.shift(-1).eq(4).any(1)

In [1086]: df[s | s.shift()]
Out[1086]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rolling` for general solution working with any pattern:

```
pat = np.asarray([3,4])
N = len(pat)

mask= (df['C'].rolling(window=N , min_periods=N)
              .apply(lambda x: (x==pat).all(), raw=True)
              .mask(lambda x: x == 0) 
              .bfill(limit=N-1)
              .fillna(0)
              .astype(bool))

df = df[mask]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

**Explanation**:

- use [`rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) and test pattern
- replace `0`s to `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html)
- use `bfill` with `limit` for filling first NANs values by last previous one
- [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `NaN`s to `0`
- last cast to bool by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)

Comment: why do you bfill?

Comment: @oren_isp - So explanation is necessary? Always is pattern with length `2` ?

Comment: @oren_isp - OK, `bfill` is necessary for matching if first values of column matched pattern. Ii replace NaNs by 1. If not mached patter it repalce by `0`